# Difference between libs-snapshot & libs-snapshot-local?

Tags: repository, artifactory

In our project, we are migrating from ant scripts to gradle build.

We are going to use artifactory as a repo manager in our company to store artifacts.

I have seen some repository stuff in artifactory, consisting of `libs-snapshot-local` as a remote repository and `libs-snapshot` as virtual repository. Same with releases repo `libs-release-local` and `libs-release`.

Can any one of you explain what is the difference between them? Can I deploy the artifacts to both of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Virtual repository, as explained in [the documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories), unify other remote, local and virtual repositories to provide a single URL for resolution.

`libs-snapshot-local` is not a remote repository, but a local repository. As explained in [the documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories), local repositories are physical repositories in Artifactory which serve as targets for your deployments.

You don't need to deploy artifacts to both of them. Deploying to local makes the deployed artifacts available for retrieval from the virtual.

Comment: Yaa gone through documentation. Thanks @JBaruch. And if possible, can you answer me another 2 questions which relates to this slightly. 
1) If I want to upload war file into different versions of snapshot like 1.0 & 0.1. How would I do that dynamically in gradle?
2) And if I want to have both snapshot & release script in build.gradle, such that I can decide on the run time whether to go into libs-release-local or libs-snapshots local. How would I do that?

Comment: I am just moving to maven, and I can understand the advantages of the concept of a repository manager. However, the documentation makes a lot of assumptions about how much users knows. I know you can't or don't want to teach new users, but I wish that documentation made less of an assumption about how expert people are. Sometimes I think the developers are so tied into their project they forget how much above regular people they are in terms of their subject matter expertise. I have been using Artifactory, and it is helpful, but I probably only touch a subset of functionality due to ignorance.

Comment: @phoenix those look like fine questions by their own merit. Feel free to post the links here :)

Comment: @BillR take a look at [DZone Repository Manager Refcard[(http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/binary-repository-management). It might suite your needs.